# Python how can I read file of dictionaries with newline?

Tags: python, json, file

I have a file of json objects like this

```
dict\n
dict\n
.
.
.
```

This is how I make this file

```
with open(old_surveys.json, 'a+') as f1:
            for survey in data:
                surv = {"sid": survey["id"],
                    "svy_ttl": survey["title"]),
                    "svy_link": survey["href"]
                    }
                f1.seek(0)
                
                if str(surv["sid"]) not in f1.read():
                    json.dump(surv, f1)
                    f1.write('\n')
            f1.close()
```

Now I want to check if a specific dict is in the file `old_surveys.json`. How can I read it line by line?

Comment: Are you aware that you keep reading the entire file every time you've written a record, to see if the record was already there? You want to check for the presence of a specific dictionary - does it need to be the whole dictionary, or do you just want to check for the presence of a dictionary that shares the `sid`?

Comment: @Grismar yea, is there a better way to check the duplication?

Comment: @Grismar the whole dictionary and the one that shares the `sid` are basically the same thing.

Comment: unless you know something about the actual data that I don't, it seems to me that there could be a survey with the same `sid`, but with an updated `svy_ttl` or `svy_link` - in that case, OP may want to replace it (or perhaps not - who knows, it's why I'm asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the duplication in a more efficient way, and answering your question:

```
import json

with open('old_surveys.json', 'a+') as f1:
    # first load all the old surveys in a dictionary
    f1.seek(0)
    surveys = {}
    for line in f1:
        d = json.loads(line)
        surveys[d['sid']] = d
    # then write any new ones from data
    for survey in data:
        if survey['id'] not in surveys:
            json.dump({'sid': survey['id'], 'svy_ttl': survey['title'], 'svy_link': survey['href']}, f1)
            f1.write('\n')
    # this line is not needed, it closes thanks to with
    # f1.close()
```

Optionally, you may want to still create `surv` and write that to the file, as well as adding it to `surveys`, if you expect duplicates in `data`.

```
import json

with open('old_surveys.json', 'a+') as f1:
    f1.seek(0)
    surveys = {}
    for line in f1:
        d = json.loads(line)
        surveys[d['sid']] = d
    for survey in data:
        if survey["id"] not in surveys:
            surv = {"sid": survey["id"], "svy_ttl": survey["title"], "svy_link": survey["href"]}
            surveys[surv['id']] = surv
            json.dump(surv, f1)
            f1.write('\n')
```

If you don't really need the surveys, but just the identifiers, this is more efficient:

```
import json

with open('old_surveys.json', 'a+') as f1:
    f1.seek(0)
    surveys = set()
    for line in f1:
        d = json.loads(line)
        surveys.add(d['sid'])
    for survey in data:
        if survey["id"] not in surveys:
            surv = {"sid": survey["id"], "svy_ttl": survey["title"], "svy_link": survey["href"]}
            surveys.add(surv['id'])
            json.dump(surv, f1)
            f1.write('\n')
```

Here, the dictionary has been replaced with a `set()`, since you only need to keep track of the identifiers, but you wouldn't have access to the rest of the surveys after this section (unlike before).

Comment: Note that, like OP's example, this is missing the actual definition of `data` - I'm assuming OP has that somewhere and it would work for their example code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file like this

```
{"sid": 1, "svy_ttl": "foo", "svy_link": "foo.com"}
{"sid": 2, "svy_ttl": "bar", "svy_link": "bar.com"}
{"sid": 3, "svy_ttl": "Alice", "svy_link": "alice.com"}
{"sid": 4, "svy_ttl": "Bob", "svy_link": "bob.com"}
```

How about this code snippet? I'm not sure this is the optimal solution tho

```
import json


def target_dict_exists(target_dict, filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if json.loads(line) == target_dict:
                return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    target = {"sid": 3, "svy_ttl": "Alice", "svy_link": "alice.com"}
    print(target_dict_exists(target, "test.txt"))
```